# Optimizing performance for mysql ORDER BY col_a * col_b without adding col_c=col_a*col_b

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to optimize such a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tid=8 ORDER BY col_a*col_b DESC LIMIT 10;
```

col_a and col_b are of type INT

I'm of-course aware I can create col_c that holds that data, but was hoping MySQL has some way to save that data directly in an index.

This query currently takes around 10seconds (depending on how many rows match the relevant key). This is an example EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tbl ref tid_uid, tid_col_a  tid_uid 4   const   396816  Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: I don't think any index will optimize for that, unless you create a `col_c` with the result of the multiplication.

Comment: agree with @TomvanderWoerdt , you will need a third column that updates on trigger of changing col_a or col_b, and index by it.

Comment: Multiplication on SQL may be done with sum: SUM(A*B), if it works in ORDER BY statement i dont know

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582191/sql-query-for-multiplication

Comment: Try this : SELECT id,col_a*col_b as col_c FROM tbl WHERE p_key=8 ORDER BY col_c DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: @IesusSonesson multiplication on MySQL also works like I wrote it, the problem I'm trying to solve is performance of this query.

Comment: @senthilbp why would that change the performance of the query?

Comment: Are you actually experiencing performance issues already? If so, perhaps share with us the findings.

Comment: @Jack Yes - I've updated questions with details (10seconds query + EXPLAIN output)

Comment: what engine do you use? did you tried to to change 'sort_buffer_size` or `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 0):

You asked whether there's any way to optimize ordering when the ORDER BY clause contains expressions or functions.

No. There isn't any way that's based on indexes. MySQL simply doesn't have function indexes.

So, you're going to have to do some kind of application-domain optimization based on understanding of the meaning of your data.

For example, if col_a and col_b values are both positive and always less than or equal to some particular value, you might be able to use some kind of bounding assumption in a WHERE clause to eliminate smaller values. But this may be a case of premature optimization.